# Responding to “shall” question

Tags: grammar

> 18. Shall we ask him to come early?
>
> A. That's really not necessary.
> B. Any time at all.
> C. Yes, we shall.

Should I answer the C because of the question start with shall?
Or it is wrong. Please guide me.

Answer (score 4):

You should recognise this as not being a true "question", but a "suggestion" (phrased as a question).  The speaker is not asking if something is true or false, but offering an idea and asking for your comment.

All are grammatically correct. But B is a non-sequitur. It doesn't respond to the suggestion.  C is an answer to a question, but we aren't being asked what shall happen, but asked for an opinion on the suggestion.

A is the only answer that responds appropriately to the suggestion.